# How to apply font-face only to a certain range of Unicode characters

Tags: css, unicode

A string queried from database look like this `អាស័យដ្ឋានបច្ចុប្បន្ន 123, Street: National Road 3, ភូមិ ១, អូរឫស្សីទី ២, ៧មករា, ភ្នំពេញ តទៅនេះហៅថាភាគី«ក»។`

I used font face `font-family: 'Battambang', cursive;`. The ASCII characters look good using that font, but the other characters inside the string look a bit cumbersome.

Rendering on browser, it looks like this:

[image: View on Browser]

If I remove font-face the non-Unicode characters look good, but the Unicode characters don’t.

[image: Removing font-face]

Therefore, is there any CSS trick I can use to apply the font only to certain Unicode characters but not to others?

Comment: Check out `unicode-range`.

Comment: also you should note that `element{font-family: font1, font2, font3}` will automatically try to fallback to `font2` if the glyph is not supported in `font1`.

Comment: Technical note:  They are *all* Unicode characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the Battambang typeface doesn’t contain those characters, they’re falling back to what you specified: cursive. Use the one that would normally be inherited instead.

```css
font-family: Battambang, Roboto; /* or whatever it would be normally */
```

For typefaces that *do* contain characters you want excluded, you’ll also need to specify a [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range):

```css
@font-face {
    src: /* … */;
    font-family: Battambang;
    unicode-range: U+1780-17FF, U+200B-200C, U+25CC;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works just fine. Since it is quite new syntax to me, i'm not quite clear about `unicode-range`. You said to use `unicode-range` to exclude character from the font specified `Battambang`, however from document link in your answer said `The unicode-range CSS descriptor sets the specific range of characters to be used from a font defined by @font-face[....]`. It meaning differently from what you said, 'include' vs. 'exclude'. Thanks.