# Apply custom font to Unicode range while preserving font of characters outside range

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, cjk

My goal is to apply a custom font that I have to a range of Unicode characters (Chinese in this case), *and have the remaining characters retain their font*.

Via this Stack Overflow question: [How to apply font-face only to a certain range of Unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45705472/how-to-apply-font-face-only-to-a-certain-range-of-unicode-characters) and looking at the source code of [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-custom-fonts/hckjchjpkmbihoocajjpjajkggbccgee?hl=en&authuser=1) Chrome extension that forces custom fonts, I was able to create the below CSS code. The code is to be inserted as `<style>` element contents above the `<head>` of a webpage.

```css
@font-face {
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "李国夫手写体";
  src: local("李国夫手写体");
  unicode-range: U+2E80-9FFF, U+F900-FAFF, U+FE30-FE4F, U+20000-2FA1F;
}
@font-face {
  font-style: bolder;
  font-family: "李国夫手写体";
  src: local("李国夫手写体");
  unicode-range: U+2E80-9FFF, U+F900-FAFF, U+FE30-FE4F, U+20000-2FA1F;
}
:not(pre):not(code):not(textarea):not(tt):not(kbd):not(samp):not(var) {
  font-family: "李国夫手写体" !important;
}
```

This does indeed change the fonts in the range to my custom one. However, it also sets all the fonts used by other characters outside the range to a default value.

Before:
[image: before image]

After：
[image: after image]

*Here the difference in English fonts is not super clear, but there are changes if you look closely at the font. The difference is however significant with different size/custom/fancy fonts — see below image.

[image: Big difference]

**Is there any way of applying a custom font to only characters in some range without affecting other characters?**

Comment: Would require a class for the unicode font-family. Something like `<p>some regular text <span class="unicode">uni text</span> some more regular text</p>`.

Comment: @RenevanderLende the ultimate goal of such a styling is to insert it as a `style` element above the `head` of different webpages as a browser extension, changing the font of characters that fall between that range for all sites visited. Is that not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but the crux is that not all font families support all 48,000 unicode characters. Apart from any language specific font-family (like Chinese, Korean, etc.) To support most unicode you will most likely have to create a selector with a popular font family like Times New Roman, Arial, Helvectica, Noto. ....And for the rest accept that you will have to disappoint some people in certain cases. Not to mention unicode issues on mobile phones....